# Entity Framework Core Fluent Api config join table record depend on value

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a join table `UserSystem` which is:

```
public class UserSystem
    {
        public int UserSystemId { get; set; }

        public int SystemId { get; set; }
        public virtual System System { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
        public int AddedByUserId { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
        public int? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

And a configuration

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserSystem> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("UserSystem", DbSchemas.Dbo);
            builder.HasKey(e => e.UserSystemId);
            builder.HasOne(bc => bc.User).WithMany(b => b.UserSystems).HasForeignKey(bc => bc.UserId);
            builder.HasOne(bc => bc.System).WithMany().HasForeignKey(bc => bc.SystemId);
        }
```

Now I want to be able to add new `UserSystem` with same `UserId` and `SystemId`, but only when same data not exists with `Deleted == 0`. If for example `UserId = 1` and `SystemId = 1` are in database, but it has `Deleted = 1` then I want to be able to add same record again with `Deleted = 0`, but not being able to add same data when any record with that data has `Deleted = 0`. How can I achieve it in FluentApi?

Comment: Unique index with [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter)?

Comment: @IvanStoev by this? `builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.UserId, x.SystemId }).HasFilter("[Deleted] = 0");` It does not work. I can still add anything to database.

Comment: @IvanStoev I forgot to use .IsUnique(). Now it works. Thanks.